# How to arrange the news section in array php for my website

Tags: php, arrays

i'm looking to learn how to place the array **left-right-left** (3 new news section). As for now i can only do the simple array for my news section.

Take a look at how i want it to be in **array php**..

[News Section Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcFbM.png)

If u have references for me to study would be much more easier :)

Thank you

Comment: *"If u have references for me to study would be much more easier :)"* - Yes, little thing the cool kids use: "Google" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have tried to search and try to learn that array but unfortunately it didnt worked. it seems like i cant find it in google.

Comment: What does the linked picture have to do with a PHP array? Show us some code for the PHP arrays, it might make it clearer what you are actually asking...?